# Eclipse ssl certificate access issue

Tags: eclipse, ssl-certificate

I am currently using eclipse for my project. And i have configured a maven project. Initially i was using java version 11 and its location was set in environment variables. Now i have upgraded to jdk version 21 because eclipse doesnot support java version 11. In the eclipse’s .ini file i have provided the new jdk version. Along with this i have also added the key store location which is nothing but the jdk 21/lib/security/cacerts.
Note i havenot changed the java home in environment variables its still pointing to jdk11.

I have a run configuration added for the maven project which has jre runtime pointing to jdk11. Now when run the project i get suncert error  no valid certificate found for requested target.

I had installed the certificates into jdk21/lib/security/cacerts since this is the keystore location given in .ini file. But i was getting the same error. Then when i installed the certificate into jdk11/lib/security/cacerts the application started working.
Can someone explain why eclipse didnot consider the keystore location specified in .ini file?

I tried adding it into the jdk11/lib/security/cacerts the application started working. Actually eclipse should have looked for the certificates from the keystore location specified in .ini file.

Comment: Eclipse supports Java 11, 8, 7, 6, 5 and even older Java versions. The Java used to run Eclipse is independent from the supported Java that you can use in your projects. Revert your changes in `eclipse.ini` and configure your Java JDKs/JREs you want to use in your projects in preferences _Java > Installed JREs_ instead.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to reply @howlger. I would like to understand why eclipse didnt look for ssl certificate from the keystore i had given in .ini file

Comment: `eclipse.ini` is for running the Eclipse IDE, not to your projects (you can, but do not have to, use the same Java JRE or JDK to run Eclipse as to run your application you developed with Eclipse). Or are you developing an Eclipse plugin? In _Run > Run Configurations..._ go to your launch/run configuration and hit the _Show Command Line_ button. This command line command is executed when you hit the _Run_ button in Eclipse to run your application.